# Prompt is blank after updating ConEmu

Tags: conemu

Since updating ConEmu my prompt is either blank (just a flashing cursor) or behind one command. How do I correct this?

edit:

Run after a settings reset and save

Run via: "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe"

Version 150705 [64] also tried 150728

Tasks tried:

- cmd.exe /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd"
- cmd.exe

Screen shots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBBfb.jpg

It's not occuring on my Win10 Desktop running 150513 [64]

edit:
The issue is not present on the problematic machine when using the portable 150513 build.

Comment: No screenshot, no ConEmu version, no startup command...

Comment: I've added additional information.

Comment: You are using clink! And more, you are using *old* clink!

Comment: Ah, yes. That fixes it. I forgot they weren't bundled. Thanks!